# PHP ciclo while imprime resultados no deseados

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo una factura en la cual me permite pagar 1 o varias cuotas del contrato al mismo tiempo. Cada pago se guarda con la fecha y hora en que se hizo. Por ejemplo si pago 3 cuotas al mismo tiempo, todas las 3 tienen la misma hora y fecha.

Mi tabla en MySQL es la siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE `alquiler_renta_detalle`
(
   `codigo_factura` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `cuota_renta` text collate utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
   `fecha_cuota_pagada` date NOT NULL,
   `hora_cuota_pagada` time NOT NULL,
   KEY `CODIGO_FACTURA` (`codigo_factura`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;


//aqui he realizado dos pagos, el primero de 3 cuotas y el segundo con 2 cuotas

INSERT INTO `alquiler_renta_detalle` VALUES (2, '1', '2018-03-11', '08:08:02');
INSERT INTO `alquiler_renta_detalle` VALUES (2, '2', '2018-03-11', '08:08:02');
INSERT INTO `alquiler_renta_detalle` VALUES (2, '3', '2018-03-11', '08:08:02');
INSERT INTO `alquiler_renta_detalle` VALUES (2, '4', '2018-03-11', '08:48:48');
INSERT INTO `alquiler_renta_detalle` VALUES (2, '5', '2018-03-11', '08:48:48');
```

Mi problema esta en cuando voy a mostrar el historial de pago, debería de salir:

```
Cuotas: 1,2,3
Cuotas: 4,5
```

Pero mi arroja esto:

```
Cuotas: 1
Cuotas: 1,2
Cuotas: 1,2,3
Cuotas: 4
Cuotas: 4,5
```

Aqui dejo el codigo en php

```
<?php
    //conexion a la base de datos
    include("../conexion.php"); 
    $conec=Conectarse();

    //consulta a la tabla "alquiler_renta_detalle"
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM alquiler_renta_detalle WHERE codigo_factura=2 ORDER BY cuota_renta + 0 ASC";
    $result = mysql_query ($sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <!--si la consulta es correcta comienza el siguiente IF-->
    <?php
        if($result>0) {

            $hora_pasada=0;

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
                //$row[4] representa al campo donde fue guardado la hora en la cuota fue pagada
                if ($row[4]==$hora_pasada) {
                    //$row[2] representa el numero de cuota pagada.
                    $cuotas=$cuotas.",".$row[2];
                }else{

                    $hora_pasada=$row[4];
                    $cuotas=$row[2];
                }

                echo "Cuotas: ".$cuotas."<br>";
            }
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Estaré muy agradecido si alguien puede ayudarme.

Comment: Si el bucle te añade las cuotas en la variable `$cuotas`, tendrás que hacer el `echo "Cuotas: ".$cuotas."<br>";` fuera de él, a continuación.

Comment: Si lo coloco fuera del bucle while, solo me arroja el ultimo valor guardado en $cuotas... lo cual vendria siendo: Cuotas: 4,5.

Y deberia ser: 

Cuotas: 1,2,3
Cuotas: 4,5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes obtener las cuotas directamente con una consulta SQL

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cuota_renta SEPARATOR ', ') FROM `alquiler_renta_detalle` GROUP BY fecha_cuota_pagada, hora_cuota_pagada
```

Resultado:

```
+------------------------------------------+
| GROUP_CONCAT(cuota_renta SEPARATOR ', ') |
+------------------------------------------+
|                                  1, 2, 3 |
|                                     4, 5 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Tu página quedaría así:

```
<?php
//conexion a la base de datos
include("../conexion.php"); 
$conec=Conectarse();

//consulta a la tabla "alquiler_renta_detalle"
$sql = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(cuota_renta SEPARATOR ', ') FROM alquiler_renta_detalle GROUP BY fecha_cuota_pagada, hora_cuota_pagada;";
$result = mysql_query ($sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<!--si la consulta es correcta comienza el siguiente IF-->
<?php
    if($result>0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
                //Obtenemos la primera columna, el GROUP_CONCAT
                $cuotas = $row[0]
                echo "Cuotas: ".$cuotas."<br>";
            }

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Estoy tratando de insertar esa linea de codigo que publicaste anteriormente y no puedo consultar de forma correcta... no me arroja nada ahora. Tal vez podrias ser un poco mas especifico? Nunca antes habia usado GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: He añadido el código final a la respuesta.`GROUP_CONCAT` muestra los valores de una columna, en este caso `cuota_renta`, separándolos por comas, agrupándolos por `fecha_cuota_pagada` y `hora_cuota_pagada`.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me funciona a la perfección. Me has salvado